# Promises inside a recursive function

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
function load(lab, el) {
  return Promise.all([Util.loadHtml(lab), Util.loadScript(lab)])
    .then(function(responses) {
      parse(responses[0], el, responses[1]);
    });
}

function parse(html, parent, context) {
  var children = [].slice.call(html.childNodes).filter(function (item) { return item.nodeType === 1 || item.nodeType === 3; });

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];

    if (child.tagName.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
      load(child.tagName.toLowerCase(), parent);
    }
    else {
      var parsedNode = parseNode(child, context);
      parent.appendChild(parsedNode);
      if (child.hasChildNodes())
        parse(child, parsedNode, context);
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, that's what it should do:

1. In my app.js I call the `load` function, that will import two files, one `html` and one `js`, and when the promise of those requests is fullfilled, it calls a function named `parse` which will loop into the HTML and will parse some strings with the class declared in the JS file.
2. Inside the loop, it's possible to find some custom tag, for example `<my-element>`, and then, it will try to load `my-element.html` and `my-element.js`, and it will loop inside that HTML too.
3. As you can see in the code, I pass the parent and the context, so after finishing all the loopings, the 'big' parent should have all the other components inside it.

**The problem**

Since the `load` function returns a promise, and I'm calling it synchronously, it immediately returns, and for that reason, the children is not placed inside the correct parents.

If I was doing that in C#, for example, or with the ES7 `async` and `await` keywords, that would be pretty easy. But I have no idea how can I call that `load` function asynchronously. Any guesses?

Comment: I can't see how it would put it into its incorrect parent because it's `async`.

Comment: Uh, if you're filtering also for text nodes, you should not access their `.tagName` without checking that it's an element.

Comment: @Bergi in fact, my code is much bigger than this. I've simplified it for the context of my question - I check the types of the nodes etc :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is asynchronous, it should return a promise. Always. Even (or: especially) in `then` callbacks.

If you produce multiple promises in that loop, you can await them via `Promise.all`:

```
function load(lab, el) {
  return Promise.all([Util.loadHtml(lab), Util.loadScript(lab)])
    .then(function(responses) {
      return parse(responses[0], el, responses[1]);
//    ^^^^^^
    });
}

function parse(html, parent, context) {
  var children = [].slice.call(html.childNodes).filter(function (item) { return item.nodeType === 1 || item.nodeType === 3; });

  return Promise.all(children.map(function(child, i) {
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    if (child.tagName.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
      return load(child.tagName.toLowerCase(), parent);
//    ^^^^^^
    } else {
      var parsedNode = parseNode(child, context);
      parent.appendChild(parsedNode);
      if (child.hasChildNodes())
        return parse(child, parsedNode, context);
//      ^^^^^^
    }
  }));
}
```

> If I was doing that in C#, for example, or with the ES7 async and await keywords, that would be pretty easy. But I have no idea how can I call that `load` function asynchronously

Yeah, you really should consider using those. Or you can emulate them with ES6 generator functions and a runner (as provided by many popular promise libraries). But you're using a transpiler anyway, right?

Writing `load` would be quite easy with them:

```
async function load(lab, el) {
  var responses = await Promise.all([Util.loadHtml(lab), Util.loadScript(lab)]);
  return parse(responses[0], el, responses[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Typescript, and it doesn't have async / await implemented yet :(

Comment: Does it have generators?

Comment: Not yet either, but it seems it will have really soon!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .reduce to achieve that:

```
function load(lab, el) {
  return Promise.all([Util.loadHtml(lab), Util.loadScript(lab)])
    .then(function(responses) {
      return parse(responses[0], el, responses[1]);
    });
}

function parse(html, parent, context) {
  var children = [].slice.call(html.childNodes).filter(function (item) { return item.nodeType === 1 || item.nodeType === 3; });

  // What this return is a promise chained through all of its children
  // So until all children get resolved, this won't get resolved.
  return children.reduce(function(promise, child, idx) {
    var childPromise = null;
    if (child.tagName.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
      // Start to load the contents, until childPromise is resolved, the final
      // can't be resolved.
      childPromise = load(child.tagName.toLowerCase(), parent);
    } else {
      var parsedNode = parseNode(child, context);
      parent.appendChild(parsedNode);
      // If it has child, also make it return a promise which will be resolved
      // when child's all children parsed.
      if (child.hasChildNodes()) {
        childPromise = parse(child, parsedNode, context);
      }
    }

    // It's either null, which means it'll be resolved immediately,
    // or a promise, which will wait until its childs are processed.
    return promise.then(function() {
      return childPromise;
    });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Then, when iteratin through the children, it'll keep chaining the promise, each child can either load or parse independently, and until all children is resolved, the promise return from `parse` get resolved. So you can now use it  like:

```
parse(THE PARAM OF ROOT).then(function() {
    // All the big parents's children are now parsed.
    console.log('All done');
});
```

EDITED: as [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) suggests, [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is better then .reduce, as it'll reject immediately when any of the children(grandchildren) fails. And as [The more acceptable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315195/1737627) is posted, I'll just give a link to it, instead of add the `.all` version.

And [JavaScript Promises#chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-chaining) may help you too.

Comment: You should really consider doing `return Promise.all([promise, childPromise])` instead of this `.then()` thing. That way, it would immediately reject on errors.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for the reminding, just forgot the `.all` when writing the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where you got it wrong:

```
if (child.tagName.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
      load(child.tagName.toLowerCase(), parent);
    }
```

You are passing the `parent` of the `child` object to be the `parent` of the `grandchild` object. You probably need to pass `child` as parent of the `grandchild`.

Comment: There is no 'logic' error in the code. In fact, if I'm not using any custom tag, it works like a charm, the problem only occurs when I need to load other htmls/js, and it immediately execute the function, before the `parse` method being executed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was simpler than I thought it would be:

```
function load(lab, el) {
  return Promise.all([Util.loadHtml(lab), Util.loadScript(lab)])
    .then(function(responses) {
      return parse(responses[0], el, responses[1]); // return here
    });
}

function parse(html, parent, context) {
  var children = [].slice.call(html.childNodes).filter(function (item) { return item.nodeType === 1 || item.nodeType === 3; });

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];

    if (child.tagName.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
      return load(child.tagName.toLowerCase(), parent); // return here
    }
    else {
      var parsedNode = parseNode(child, context);
      parent.appendChild(parsedNode);
      if (child.hasChildNodes())
        parse(child, parsedNode, context);
    }
  }
}
```

Since my parsing must be synchronous (because of the order etc), and the only thing I needed was waiting for the `load` function to finish before going back to `parse`, the only things I changed was to instead of directly calling the `parse` function inside the  `load` one and vice-versa, I'm now using the `return`, since then it will wait for the execution, before going back to the caller.

---

Other thing that worked and it was even better for my use case: I ended up creating a clone of my custom element, and appending it to the parent, calling the loading function passing it. Doing that, I could load all its children async and without the problem of not being attached to the DOM.

Faster execution, and better readability!

Comment: Well it doesn't look like that does work. It might for your simple example test case, but it won't in general. You hardly want to break out of the loop (?), and your recursive call to `parse` is (possibly) asynchronous as well so you must not forget to take it into care.